# How to get HttpSession attributes from jsf web page

Tags: jsf, xhtml, httpsession

I am trying to write some code in jsf scriptlet to get a attribute from HttpSession and compare with a UI value (to display a pop-up when both session and UI values are same ) .

Comment: Maybe this can help:

HttpSession session = request.getSession(true).
String username = (String)session.getAttribute("username");

Comment: I have done the same in java class but I need to write the above code in jsf scriptlet - to compare it with a UI value on AJAX call

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in JSF with EL: `#{session.getAttribute('key') eq uiValue}`.

List of all JSF EL objects can be found [here](http://incepttechnologies.blogspot.si/p/jsf-implicit-objects.html).

Comment: That helped.. Thanks alot .